# copy and append specific lines to a file with specific name format?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am copying some specific lines from one file to another.

```
   grep '^stringmatch' /path/sfile-*.cfg  >> /path/nfile-*.cfg
```

Here what's happening: its creating a new file called `nfile-*.cfg` and copying those lines in that. The file names `sfile- *` and `nfile- *` are randomly generated and are generally followed by a number. Both `sfile-*` and `nfile-*` are existing files and there is only one such file in the same directory. Only the number that follows is randomly generated. The numbers following in `sfile` and `nfile` need not be same. The files are not created simultaneously but are generated when a specific command is given. But some lines from one file to the another file needs to be appended.

Comment: And does the `nfile-*.cfg` contain the correct lines from `sfile`?

Comment: yes, the newly generated `nfile-*.cfg` has the correct lines from `sfile`.

Comment: Isn't it a bit dangerous to use globbing in redirection? It would work in the intended way, if you have exactly one file starting with `nfile-`, but would give surprising results otherwise.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, what version of the bash shell are you using?  As @user1934428 mentioned, if you have one and only one matching file, it should work.  When I try with more than one matching file, I get an `ambiguous redirect` error from bash.  I only manage to create a file with a `*` in the name if no matching file exists.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get which is the problem/question here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you actually want something like

```
for f in /path/sfile-*.cfg; do
    grep '^stringmatch' "$f" >"/path/nfile-${f#/path/sfile-}"
done
```

This will loop over all `sfile` matches and create an `nfile` target file with the same number after the dash as the corresponding source `sfile`. (The parameter substitution `${variable#prefix}` returns the value of `variable` with any leading match on the pattern `prefix` removed.)

If there is only one matching file, the loop will only run once. If there are no matches on the wildcard, the loop will still run once unless you enable `nullglob`, which changes the shell's globbing behavior so that wildcards with no matches expand into nothing, instead of to the wildcard expression itself. If you don't want to enable `nullglob`, a common workaround is to add this inside the loop, before the `grep`;

```
    test -e "$f" || break
```

If you want the loop to only process the first match if there are several, add `break` on a line by itself before the `done`.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question correctly, you want to output to an existing `nfile`, which has a random number in it, but instead the shell is creating a file with an asterisk in it, so literally `nfile-*.cfg`.

This is happening because the `nfile` doesn't exist when you first run the command. If the file doesn't exist, `bash` will fail to expand `nfile-*.cfg` and will instead use the `*` as a literal character. This is correct behaviour in `bash`.

So, it looks like the problem is that the `nfile` doesn't exist when you start your `grep`. You'll need to create one.

I'll leave code to others, but I hope the explanation is useful.

Comment: @triplee Without the backticks, the `*` won't be expanded... Try running `foo=*; echo "$foo"` with the double quotes and you'll get `*` rather than a directory listing. Not my favourite `bash` feature, but I'm sure it makes sense! Can I have that upvote back, please?

Comment: The error is where you use quotes, which obviously inhibit wildcard expansion. (Generally speaking, the common error is people not quoting variables where they should, so in that sense, this is an improvement...)

Comment: In this case, I actually want the expansion to happen in the `NFILE=` line. If it happens in the test, `-e` is going to fail with an error if there is more than one `nfile` already. The real problem with my coding is that it'll match an existing file with a failed glob `*` in it :-) That said, if the coding is setting you right off, feel free to edit and replace the backtick with `(*)`. I usually avoid arrays in `bash`, but it'd look nice in this case.

Comment: If the wildcard expands to more than one file, quoting the resulting list of files in `[ ! -e` will erroneously look like there are no matches. This will also work incorrectly if there are matching file names with irregular whitespace in them. I posted a separate answer which solves this in a slightly different way where these corner cases are not problematic.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Let me remove the code and leave the explanation, which I hope is useful.